# how to get a value from database and display the calculated value before clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

branch(database)
source destination distance
bengaluru  chennai 500

```
    <?php
    $db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","courier");
    if (isset($_POST['weight'])) {
    $sour=$_POST['source'];
    $dest=$_POST['dest'];
    $weight=$_POST['weight'];
    $sql="SELECT distance FROM branch WHERE source='$sour' AND destination='$dest'";
    $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $amt=$row['distance']*$weight*10;
    echo $amt;
    }
    ?>
```

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <title>BOOKING</title>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <link rel="stylesheet" 

 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>
          <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <style>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="source">SOURCE</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="source" id="src">
            <option>SELECT</option>
            <option>BANGALORE</option>
            <option>CHENNAI</option>
            <option>BOMBAY</option>
            <option>KOLKATA</option>
            <option>HYDERABAD</option>
            <option>THIRUVANANTHAPURAM</option>
          </select>
        </div>
     <div class="form-group">
          <label for="dest">DESTINATION</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="dest" id="dst">
            <option>SELECT</option>
            <option>BANGALORE</option>
            <option>CHENNAI</option>
            <option>BOMBAY</option>
            <option>KOLKATA</option>
            <option>HYDERABAD</option>
            <option>THIRUVANANTHAPURAM</option>
          </select>
        </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="weight">WEIGHT(in kgs):</label>
          <input type="textarea" class="form-control" id="weight " placeholder="Enter Weight" name="weight">
        </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="stadd">AMOUNT:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="amt" id="amt">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" >Submit</button>
      </form>
```

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('change','#dst',function(){
        var source=$('#src').val();
        var destination=$('#dst').val(); 
        var weight=$('#weight').val();
        $.ajax({
          method:"post",
          url:"amount.php",
          data:{source:'source',dest:'destination',weight:weight}

        })
        .done(function(data){
          $("#amt").val(data);
        });

    });

  </script>
```

I need to retrieve value from branch say distance and then calculate amount which is equal to weight*distance*10
I tried doing it this way but its not showing the value in amount field 
I have tried using ajax,php and jquery for this but I am new to it so I am not able to figure whats wrong with the code

Comment: where is your ajax code? Here you need to write ajax on `onblur` or `onchange` event which will call ajax and from PHP file you can get done your calculated thing and send it back to same text with its id "stadd"

Comment: if you want to show calculated data before hitting submit button then on destination change call a jquery function which will send a request to a new php page where you have query code , you have to send destination as well as source data in that ajax. php code will return that data back to your current page and you have to just paste it to corresponding field

Comment: `$sql="SELECT distance FROM branch WHERE username='$sour' AND 
      password='$dest'";` this looks fishy to me. you added source as username and destination as password and asking for distance? Means what's going on here?

Comment: that is source not username and destination not password

Answer (score 1):

Onchange destination you can send ajax request to calculate the value.

```
$(document).on('change', '.destination', function(){

    $.get('/url', function(res)
    {
       console.log(res);
    });
    });
```

In res you can get value.